# English keyboard: diacritics instead of double quotes

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout, logitech

I have been using my Logitech K380 with QWERTY British English layout with KDE Plasma without any issues. I am now using it also with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS: I selected `English (UK, intl., with dead keys)` (and I tried many others...), but any time I type `"`, unless I press the space bar, it gets replaced with a `¨`. Similarly for `´`. Is there a way to keep the layout of the keyboard but *disable* this feature?

Comment: Does this happen in all applications, or just a particular one?

Comment: @ArturMeinild All applications, from RStudio to Chrome, even the Terminal.

Comment: Sounds like some other keyboard layout, for instance *English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)*, would fit your needs better.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I do not see that layout...

Comment: It's there. It's probably sorted among the English (US) layouts.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson You are right. But then the keys do not match anymore...

Comment: Maybe easiest to get used to using the space key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we talked in comments, I missed the obvious: The basic *English (UK)* layout is probably what you want.

Comment: I feel so stupid! Thanks.